# jquery validation fails on add rule with remote

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am getting the following error: [image]

This is my jQuery script:

```html
$('.email_afiliado').each(function(key, index) {

    $('#'+index.id).rules("add",
    {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url : '{{route('public.afiliado.email')}}',
            type : 'get',
            data : {
                emails: function()
                {
                    return $(this).val();
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            required: "El número de documento del afiliado es obligatorio"
        }
    })
});
```

I don't know what is incorrect